# How to remove hover effect in bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have included bootstrap css and js in my project. I can t find .nav: hover or any kind of usage. I want to remove the hover efect from a **tabset** witch generates a div with list items in it. So how do I remove the hover from the li's?

Comment: Open the page in chrome, inspect the element by right clicking on it. Toggle the element state to hover, then In the style section you will see the specific files the style is coming from

Comment: share jsfiddle for same, will be easy to help

Comment: @Josh Harrison ... thank you sir, found it ".nav-panels-custom > li > a:hover "